# knockout- x-editable not loading the select list

Tags: knockout.js, x-editable

I am new to x-editable and knockout, can anybody help me why this following code in not loading select list, intead it gives an error "Error when loading list"

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable();
        self.firstName = ko.observable();
        self.lastName = ko.observable();

        self.genders = ko.observableArray( [
            { id: 1, text: "Male" },
            { id: 2, Description: "Female"  }
        ]);

        self.gender = ko.observable();
        self.firstName = ko.observable('John');
        self.lastName = ko.observable('Doe');
        self.gender = ko.observable(2);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

    EditableManager.registerEditable();
    EditableManager.onSuccess = function (result) {

    };

});
```

The HTML

```
 <span data-type='select' data-showbuttons="false"  data-bind=" editable: gender,  editableOptions: {pk: id, options: genders, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'id'}"></span>
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated,

-George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the editableOptions, change 'options' to 'source'.

And in the self.genders, define the object key using 'value' and 'text', because I can't get optionsText and optionsValue to work.

After changing the name to the [default options](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select) in x-editable, it should work ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/fifuqixo/1/edit?html,js,output)).

Comment: I figured out later, just for reference the following works  <span data-bind=" editable:gender,  editableOptions: {name:'gender',mode: 'popup',type: 'select', source: genders ,pk: id}"></span>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the parameter `options` you need to configure it a little differently, this is especially important if you use `ko.mapping.fromJS` for your objects/arrays

**ViewModel**

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({
   selected: "a",
   myoptions: [{text:"AA", value:"a"},{text:"BB", value:"b"}]
})
```

**Select**

```
data-bind=" editable:selected, editableOptions:{
    type:'select', 
    options:myoptions, 
    optionText:'text', 
    optionsValue:'value'} "
```